# How can i mock a LUIS api call in unit testing of Bot framework . If i calling it through Root Dialog

Tags: botframework

How can i mock a LUIS api call in unit testing of Bot framework . If i calling it through  Root Dialog. From unit testing we are directly calling RootDialog. Please help me to mock the LUIS api call in BOT code.

Comment: Have you looked through the LuisTests class here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Tests/LuisTests.cs ?

Comment: Please share your code, so we can help

Comment: In this we are calling LUIS API in different way.We have created a customized dialog from that dialog we are calling a class . Inside that class we are calling LUIS API . SO , In this how can i Moq the LUIS call from Test method Please help me.

Comment: You are requesting assistance writing unit tests for a specific code structure, but you have not provided the code.  Please share your code.

Comment: Hi Eric , 
I am sorry it's not possible for me to share the code . Because it will cost the privacy